# a summary button

Tags: feature-request

I asked many questions here, and people help me a lot. Thanks.

For every question, I wish I can make a summary illustrating how I actually solved my problems. This summary is different from advice answers and is significant for people looking for solutions. So I hope such interface is provided.

Comment: See also: [Add a way to provide a guided-solution to your own answer without answering the question yourself.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38776/add-a-way-to-provide-a-guided-solution-to-your-own-answer-without-answering-the-q)

Answer (score 4):

You can always post your own answer. State clearly why you've posted the answer and reference the answers that helped you the most (as well as up-voting and accepting the one that helped you the most).

It might be best if you made the answer Community Wiki. However, if it adds **new** material not actually given in any of the existing answers then you might be OK not doing this.